# What is another way to put "mistaken about what one saw"?

Tags: word-choice, slang

Is there any more slangy/easy way of saying "mistakenly about what one saw"?
Like in the below example what else can be replaced ***Maybe I was mistaken**.*?

> A: I think I heard something in the dark.
>
> B: I didn't hear anything.
>
> A: Maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15516/230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*mistaken* is easy and unambiguous so **better use this word only.** *Still,* if you want other ways to say that, here are they...

> A: I think I heard something in the dark. 
>       B: I didn't hear anything. 
>       A: Maybe, I was *mislead about that sound*. OR Maybe, it *could be something else*! OR Maybe, I *misunderstood it as some sound.*

To avoid ambiguity, I'd prefer the second one - Maybe, it *could be something else (not sound).*

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you can say that, and if you include ways that employ artistic license, the list becomes almost infinite.

It was an illusion.

It must have been my imagination.

I'm seeing things.

I'm hearing things.

Maybe I'm just confused.

My mind is playing tricks.

If you're trying to find a phrase or word *just right* for your needs, I recommend a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing *wrong* with "Maybe I was mistaken."
It does seem odd because *Mistaken* is more formal than *maybe*.
I think it would be more congruent to say "Perhaps I was mistaken."

Something less formal with the same meaning:
"I could be wrong."